# Azure Basic to Standard SKU Load Balancer Upgrade with no downtime

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Is there a way to replace my existing basic sku LB with the standard one with no downtime suffered?

Running an 3 tier architecture app/web/DB.

My idea is to create the new standard sku, configure 100% as per basic and then simply update the Azure DNS one at a time for each of the public IPs from old (basic LB) to the new IPs (standard LB). Will that do it?

Answer (score 3):

As for as I know, it's impossible to replace your existing basic LB with the standard one with no downtime since it's not upgrading directly and you must create a new standard SKU IP address for your new LB. If IP address change, DNS update, I think there is surely more or less downtime for your network connections. Normally, you can create a new load balancer to replace the old one, then remove the backend VMs from old LB and re-add the backend VMs. You can see the details from the official [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview#migration-between-skus).

**Migrate from Basic to Standard SKU**

> 1. Create a new Standard resource (Load Balancer and Public IPs, as needed). Recreate your rules and probe definitions. If you were using
>      a TCP probe to 443/tcp previously, consider changing this probe
>      protocol to an HTTPS probe and add a path.
> 2. Create new or update existing NSG on NIC or subnet to whitelist load balanced traffic, probe, as well as any other traffic you wish to
>      permit.
> 3. Remove the Basic SKU resources (Load Balancer and Public IPs, as applicable) from all VM instances. Be sure to also remove all VM
>      instances of an availability set.
> 4. Attach all VM instances to the new Standard SKU resources.

Also, if you are interested, you can vote your voice in [Change existing Public IP SKU from Basic to Standard](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/34665910-change-existing-public-ip-sku-from-basic-to-standa) for improving Azure Networking.